# Lightbox 2 fully functional, want to make the viewed image full size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, lightbox

I am building a site that has a small preview image of a map at 281 x 348. I wanted to make a way to click the image to see it full size, which would be very zoomed in, at the original image size which 1066 x 1600. However, I wanted to get fancy and make the image pop up within the same window, dimming the page behind it.
So I got Lightbox 2 to fully work, and the image displays as a popup, but it is pretty small. I want to have it large and, what I'm assuming is the best option, is to be able to scroll up and down the image.

How should I go about doing this? Every code for Lightbox including the jquery I got directly from [here.](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested in Lightbox2, but it looks like in lightbox.js there is an option named `this.fitImagesInViewport`. Try setting that value to `false` and see if it gets the result you're looking for.

Edit: I ran a quick test, and it looks like that should do it. You can take a look at the source for lightbox.js [here](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js), so hopefully the change in your code should be fairly trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked exactly how I wanted it to. Cheers!